# #docusignAPI ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSION SigningGroups Disabled

Tags: docusignapi

Touched base with DocuSign Chat Support and they informed me that they have Enabled Signing Groups, but while testing, I'm receiving the following error:

errorCode: "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS"
message: "This Account lacks sufficient permissions. SigningGroups Disabled"

Support recommended I post on Stack Overflow to receive assistance. Given public forum, please advise where I can send my username and account information privately.

Comment: WHAT. O.o Don't go sending your username/account information to random strangers! And did their support seriously not give you any help other than to tell you to post on Stack Overflow?! What other information did they give you?

Comment: I was quite surprised too and didn't understand at first, but after looking through other docusign related questions, I have seen Docusign Developers in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well they sure don't seem to be responding to your question very quickly, do they. I just added the `docusign` tag to your question... which will show up once it gets peer reviewed, or else you do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

SigningGroups is a feature of DocuSign. Not all accounts have this feature. Most newer accounts would include it, but some accounts may have had this feature disabled in the past. 
Enabling this feature for accounts that still have it disabled require a call to our support department. Please contact them in support.docusign.com or let me know if you still have issues and I can help you.